# Is it possible to use .preventDefault() in the trigger() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I created a custom event called `slides.swap` but I want to prevent the event coming from a `click` in the `trigger()`. It's not working. How do I do that from the `trigger()`?
I know I can prevent it in the `click` function but I just want to keep everything "encapsulated".

JS:

```
tabs.on('click', 'a', function(e){
  $(this).trigger('slides.swap', e);
});

//Custome event 
tabs.find('a').bind('slides.swap', function(e){
   var self = $(this),
       selfIndex = self.parent().index(),
       targetSlide = slides.eq(selfIndex);

   e.preventDefault(); //somehow this doesn't work

   //fade in/out slides
   slides.filter('.active').stop(true, false).fadeOut(speed, function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active'); 
   });
   targetSlide.stop(true, false).fadeIn(speed).addClass('active');
   tabs.removeClass('selected');
   self.parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why do you need this custom event. Couldn't you bind the anonymous function directly to the click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `preventDefault()` on the Event object for the `swap` event, which is *different* to the `click` event. Try calling `preventDefault()` on the event object you pass to the `slides.swap` handler;

```
tabs.find('a').bind('slides.swap', function(e, clickEvent){
    if (typeof clickEvent === "object" && typeof clickEvent.preventDefault === "function") { // Check the parameter was provided and that it was an event object.
        clickEvent.preventDefault();
    }

    // everything else
});
```

It must be said though that this isn't great program design. It's *wrong* to manipulate another event chain/ object from another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Matt. So how can I design my program better, if I may ask?

Comment: @Shaoz: I can't see what the functional difference is between cancelling the event within the `slides.swap` handler, or the `click` handler? Doing it inside the `click` handler would seem to be the best and right option.

Comment: Cool, I think I'll stick with cancelling from `click` handler as you said. Thanks for your tips.